# How to make final footer in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, footer

I tried to make a Footer in UITableView like in iOS app "Contacts".

[image]

I have simple tableView with simple array:
items = ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"]
I want to make empty space under last cell.

I tried to add this `cellForRowAt`:

```
 if indexPath.row == self.converterItems.count-1 {
 cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, cell.bounds.size.width, 0, 0)}
```

But it delete separator only for one cell.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        var header :UITableViewHeaderFooterView = UITableViewHeaderFooterView()

        header.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
        return header
    }
```

This method looks good, but it lost separator below last cell... 
[image]

Comment: you mean 83kohtakta label as a footer ??

Comment: what is the issue with `tableview. tableFooterView` ??

Comment: Yes. This cell counts total of contacts and have nothing under itself. I just drag it up)

Comment: @IvanKisin Have you tried tableFooter view. Also please explain what all have you tried out so that we can help you better.

Comment: @PallaviSrikhakollu updated topic.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a `UIView` and assign it to your table's footer view

```
myTableView.tableFooterView = createTableFooterView()

func createTableFooterView() -> UIView {
    let footerView = UIView()
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return footerView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the table endless. You'd better set `UITableViewStyle.grouped`

```
let tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect.zero, style: .grouped)
```

And Then:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return [].count//  your array
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "", for: indexPath)
        // your cell
        // yourIdentifier, and you should register cell Identifier for tableView at first
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return ""
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "83 KOH"
    }
}
```

Comment: Its add footer but how i could make it endless?